# Why a pitch has extra pitches on both its sides?

Tags: cricket

Why a pitch has extra pitches on both its sides? There are always 2-3 pitches on one side. And they are always covered with grass.

Comment: Imagine a scenario where a match is scheduled on a particular ground but due to unforeseen events, the pitch gets damaged. So, a ground always have multiple pitches, the one which will be used to play is trimmed while others are left grassy. Fail-safe redundancy perposes

Answer (score 4):

All grounds have more than one pitch - this is a requirement as a fresh pitch is required for each match, and pitches take time to recover and prepare. Big grounds will have 20 to 30 pitches across the square, while even very small ones will have 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

Pitch creation is a long process, those pitch are in the process to be created. Some pitches are created for net session for both team as well.

Answer (score 0):

The immediately adjacent pitches (the "square") can be used as spare pitches if the main pitch is deemed unplayable before the game. That's very rare, though, and I've never seen it happen; conditions which would render the chosen pitch unplayable almost always affect the entire ground.

However, the pitches well off​ to the side are simply practice pitches. They're far too off-centre to be used for play. Teams want to get some practice on pitches as close to the match condition as possible, but using the main pitch would risk damage and is prohibited by law 17 on any day of a match.

Edit to clarify: don't think I've ever seen a pitch swapped once handed over by the ground staff, but it's not uncommon for a club groundsman to change his mind about which pitch to prepare, if one has dried better than another, for eg. Not at professional level though; changing pitches is more complicated because of realigning the multitude of cameras and radar.